# Would my family's Schengen refusal and illegal stays affect my application?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a 25-year-old woman. I have a job but have been working only for 7 months, and receive a €380 salary. Would my mother's Schengen visa refusal affect my application for a visa? Does that make a difference to my applying for a visitor visa? This would be my first time applying for a Schengen visa. No one else in my family has been granted a Schengen visa before, although some of my uncles were illegally in the Schengen area. Would that history affect my request?

Comment: The job and your personal situation might be more of an issue than your uncles or mother's history. But we really cannot promise you anything, there is no point in asking the same vague question over and over again.

Comment: Are you referring to my job and salary?

Answer (score 3):

Your family's history does not appear relevant. The application form does not ask for the name of your parents or other relatives. It might be possible to guess that your mother is your mother based on your respective names but depending on the locale/culture, there might be no way to tell or many people with the same name. If consulates were taking decisions on that basis, they would therefore take the trouble of asking more details to be able to run a proper search.

It might be different if you are all applying at the same time or within a short time frame.